sun.security.util.DerEncoder is not accessible in sts java 17
I am running a java spring boot application in STS, and using java 17.and the build tool i am using gradle.
i am facing the compilation error called sun.security.util.DerEncoder is not accessible.
i found something that from java 16 this package is not available but while i am searching the same class called DerEncoder and some other classes,example:
import sun.security.util.DerEncoder;
import sun.security.util.DerOutputStream;
import sun.security.util.DerValue;
import sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;

it is availble in the class path in the java.base jar file and package also same.
so i am in bit of confusion mode that if the package is not available from hava 16,
then why it is included in the java.base package.
and i also tryed few suggestions like trying add
*--add-exports=java.base/sun.security.provider=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED *
but still no luck. can anybody please suggest the better solution.

As you encounter compile errors you have the source files. Then rewrite the functions that make use of those sun.* classes.
